# In react, how does one update data in firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

As a new react programmer, I'm struggling to update my form data in firebase. Please assist.

Here's my button:

```
<button onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit(this.props.match.params.id)}>
  Update
</button>
```

And here's the handler:

```
handleSubmit = (id) => {
  console.log(id);
  return this.props.firestore
  .collection("tasks")
  .doc(id)
  .update({
    title: this.props.title
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Once submitted, although I get no error, I also don't get the id logged to the console. It's like nothing really happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following changes and it seems to be pretty much working now.

I put the onSubmit in the form tag and not in the button. Since the id is obtained from params.id I realized I didn't need to pass it as a parameter - it can be obtained directly from within the onSubmit handler.

Finally, I changed this.props.title to this.state.title.

Here is the handler:

```
handleSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault();
const id = this.props.match.params.id;
console.log(id);
return this.props.firestore
  .collection("tasks")
  .doc(id)
  .update({
    title: this.state.title
  })
  .then(() => {
    this.props.history.push("/");
    window.location.reload();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error updating doc", err);
  });
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I think `onSubmit` event are not meant for `button` but `Forms`.

You must use `onClick` event on `button`.

---

**Update**

As you are using form, you must have `onSubmit` on `form` and not on `button`, like

```
<form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit(this.props.match.params.id)}>
  <button>
    Update
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's a form button. Can you submit form data through an onClick event? Doesn't it need to be an onSubmit event?

Comment: In that case also `onSubmit` should be on `Form` only and not on `button`.